# spark-submit passing --files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to pass two files in a spark-submit:

- key.jks
- trustore.jks

located as follow:

- /home/my_user/config/key.jks
- /home/my_user/config/trustore.jks

I execute the following command:

```
spark-submit --name historization \
--class com.ConsumerLauncher \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--files /home/my_user/config/key.jks,/home/my_user/config/trustore.jks \
/home/my_user/jars/app.jar
```

And I would like to treat in my code this two files for my kafka param:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "myhost",
  "group.id" -> "grp-test",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
  "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
  "ssl.truststore.password" -> "xxxx",
  "ssl.key.password" -> "xxxx",
  "ssl.keystore.password" -> "xxxx",
  //this two lines
  "ssl.truststore.location" -> "/home/my_user/config/trustore.jks",
  "ssl.keystore.location" -> "/home/my_user/config/key.jks"
  //this two line also bug
  //"ssl.truststore.location" -> getClass.getResource("/ssl/trustore.jks").getPath,
  //"ssl.keystore.location" -> getClass.getResource("/ssl/key.jks").getPath
)
```

unfortunately I obtain this error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/my_user/config/key.jks (No such file or directory)
```

do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use --files , your files are uploaded to HDFS.
You have now access this way : trustore.jks and key.jks

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "myhost",
  "group.id" -> "grp-test",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
  "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
  "ssl.truststore.password" -> "xxxx",
  "ssl.key.password" -> "xxxx",
  "ssl.keystore.password" -> "xxxx",
  //this two lines
  "ssl.truststore.location" -> "trustore.jks",
  "ssl.keystore.location" -> "key.jks"
  //this two line also bug
  //"ssl.truststore.location" -> getClass.getResource("/ssl/trustore.jks").getPath,
  //"ssl.keystore.location" -> getClass.getResource("/ssl/key.jks").getPath
)
```